# Unable to boot UBUNTU from USB in windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I could not able to dual boot ubuntu from USB. I am using windows 8.1 and the system was preinstalled with it.my model is lenovo u430p.

I disabled the secure boot option and checked it but it didn't work as it always boots windows only. Cant able to figure out even after checking the forums.So my question are:

- Is anyone facing the same problem?
- Can anyone elaborate on the steps and tell where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made your usb bootable properly. you can use [universal-usb-installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3)  to make you usb bootable on window and try again.

Comment: Yes, made it bootable through USB installer.

Comment: If you computer has UEFI boot then you should read [this on community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) as Ubuntu has trouble with the new UEFI technology.

Comment: You may find an answer here: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: The system won't always boot into the USB automatically. You have to set the higher priority to the USB or have to select the USB drive from the boot menu

Answer (score 1):

You have to do one of two things:

- First, you must make sure you burned a bootable version of Ubuntu on a USB.
- Second, you must set your BIOS priority to boot from USB first.

[Linuxlive USB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) is free, easy and safe way to make a bootable USB of not just Ubuntu, but any linux distribution. Once you have made a bootbale version of your linux distribution (Ubuntu), reboot your computer and rapidly press F4 (or F11, whichever takes you to your BIOS menu) and change the boot order for your computer from (presumably) your hard drive to your USB port and it should boot up a linux liveCD in which you can use linux without installing it. If you do plan to install linux, it will also give you onscreen instructions on what to do, step-by-step to install it onto your computer.